# Why is picocli requiring args within an ArgGroup even with the default multiplicity of 0..1?

Tags: picocli

You can find an example of the code here.
[Link to my GitHub project](https://github.com/Shawn1874/JavaPractice/tree/master/UCSD_Assignments/Lesson5Concurrency)

In the file Driver.java, you can see that I have specified an exclusive ArgGroup.  My understanding based on the documentation is that the default multiplicity is 0..1.  The documentation states, "The default is multiplicity = "0..1", meaning that by default a group may be omitted or specified once".

I have also tried to set the multiplicity explicitly to 0..1 but that did not change the behavior.  Running the program without either the -al or -rl options, the parsing throws a NullPointerException.  The framework is behaving as though one of those options is required.  That is not consistent with the [documentation](https://picocli.info/#_mutually_exclusive_options).  I should be able to run this program with only the -n option if I want.  I want the ArgGroup to be completely optional.

The program at the git hub link is a fully functioning maven project that one could clone, build, and run.  However here is the stack trace.  With no arguments specified or without the arg group.  I expect that with no arguments at all that the usage info would be printed.  Also the default multiplicity for the group is supposed to be 0..1 so I shouldn't have to specify one of the options within the arg group.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.shawnfox.java4.concurrency.Driver.call(Driver.java:58)
    at com.shawnfox.java4.concurrency.Driver.call(Driver.java:1)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1743)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$900(CommandLine.java:145)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2101)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2068)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:1935)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:1864)
    at com.shawnfox.java4.concurrency.Driver.main(Driver.java:50)
```

Comment: A NullPointerException sounds like you may have found a bug in picocli. Would you mind raising a ticket on the picocli issue tracker? What is the behavior you’re actually seeing? Is there a stack trace? I’ll try to reproduce when I get to my PC.

Comment: That is what I was thinking.  I just wanted a community opinion first just in case I was misunderstanding the documentation.  I posted the stack trace so hopefully with that my expectations are clear.  Another issue is that with no options I would get an exception but I would still expect usage (help) info to be displayed if I run with no options.  In my  mind, the arg group  should be optional itself unless I specify a multiplicity that requires it 1 or more times.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the stacktrace, that was useful! I updated my answer. If the application checks for `null` in the `call` method there will be no exception. I am not sure what you mean with "I would still expect usage (help) info to be displayed if I run with no options". That sounds like you expect picocli to consider no options invalid input and display an error, but it is not an error:  since the multiplicity is `0..1`, the arg group is optional, so not specifying it is fine, right?

Comment: Before I added the arg group, not specifying anything on the command line always  resulted in the help being displayed automatically.  I did not need to type --help to get help info.  With the argument group, that stopped happening.  Something still doesn't seem right about how it works since the arg group was added.

Comment: Sorry I don’t follow. I just checked the Driver class but I can’t see why the usage help message would be displayed when the user doesn’t specify any arguments on the command line. There are no required parameters that I can see. Am I missing something?

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Perhaps I remember when I was earlier in development that one of the parameters was required, so I observed that behavior at one point. I think you answered my question so thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome! Enjoy using picocli! If you like picocli please star the project on GitHub and tell your friends! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for adding the stack trace. I see that the `NullPointerException` occurs in the `call` method on [line 58](https://github.com/Shawn1874/JavaPractice/blob/master/UCSD_Assignments/Lesson5Concurrency/src/main/java/com/shawnfox/java4/concurrency/Driver.java#L58), not in picocli itself.

So the problem is not that picocli requires options in an optional (multiplicity = `0..1`) argument group, the problem is that the `call` method assumes that the `@ArgGroup`-annotated field will always be initialized, even if no option in the group is matched. This assumption is incorrect.

What happens is, if neither the `-al` option nor the `-rl` option are specified on the command line, then there is no match for the `SynchronizationOptions` argument group at all, so picocli will not instantiate a `SynchronizationOptions` object and the [`synchOptions` field on line 32](https://github.com/Shawn1874/JavaPractice/blob/master/UCSD_Assignments/Lesson5Concurrency/src/main/java/com/shawnfox/java4/concurrency/Driver.java#L32) will not be initialized.

This is how the picocli parser works with argument groups: for a group with multiplicity `*`, for example, picocli will create an instance of the user object for every group match and add it to the annotated collection/array field.

If no group is matched, there will be zero instances of the user object. This allows the application to detect exactly whether the group was matched or not - and if the group *is* matched, the application can rely on the invariant that for an exclusive group *only one* option was matched and has a value, and for a co-occurring group *all* options were matched and have values from the command line. (This would not be possible if picocli instantiated the user object without a match.)

The solution is to change the application to either check for `null` or initialize the `synchOptions` field in the application. The latter is probably simplest and cleanest. For example, replace:

```java
@ArgGroup(exclusive = true)
SynchronizationOptions synchOptions;
```

with

```java
@ArgGroup(exclusive = true)
SynchronizationOptions synchOptions = new SynchronizationOptions();
```

Then `synchOptions` is never `null` so the application can safely reference its fields in the `call` method:

```java
public Void call() {
    if (synchOptions.useReentrantLock) {
        // ...
```

Alternatively, check whether `synchOptions == null` in the `call` method. This allows the application to detect whether any of the synch options was matched, and if it was matched, the application can rely on the fact that at least one of the boolean fields is `true`.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  However, with a default multiplicity of 0..1 for the arg group my expectation is that the arg group itself is optional.  Therefore, not specifying either of the options should be fine and the bounded fields are default initialized boolean values.

Comment: However, you are correct that the synchOptions is null which explains the exception so I could just check for null and skip the logic.  I just don't think I should have to do that.  The booleans within it are default initialized so based on the documentation I expect for that to be created with two booleans initialized to false.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your expectations. I updated my answer with more details on when the picocli parser instantiates user objects for argument groups. Perhaps the user manual should have some more details on this as well.

Comment: I [updated the user manual](https://picocli.info/#_mutually_exclusive_options) to clarify when `@ArgGroup`-annotated fields are initialized. 
Can you take a look and see if this is sufficient?

Comment: Yes, that is very helpful.  Thanks.